# Can this heap sort be further optimized to have fewer comparisons?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, sorting

```
public static <T> void heapSort(
        T[] array, 
        Comparator<? super T> comparator) {

    int length = array.length;
    int start = (length - 1) /2; //right-most parent node

    //build heap
    while (start > -1)
        maxHeapify(array, start--, length, comparator);

    //move max to end, and rebalance.
    while (length > 1) { 
        swap(array, 0, length - 1);
        length--;
        maxHeapify(array, 0, length, comparator);
    }

}

private static <T> void maxHeapify(
        T[] array, 
        int node, 
        int length, 
        Comparator<? super T> comparator) {

    int left = 2*node + 1;
    if (left >= length)
        return;
    int right = left + 1;

    int newNode = node;

    if (comparator.compare(array[left], array[node]) > 0)
        newNode = left;

    if (right < length && comparator.compare(array[right], array[newNode]) > 0)
        newNode = right;

    if (newNode != node) {
        swap(array, node, newNode);
        maxHeapify(array, newNode, length, comparator);
    }

}
```

I wrote a merge sort that seems to be using about half as many comparisons. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I suggest you take a [look at this paper](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~breed/COMP362/HEAPSONHEAPS.pdf).  It shows how to use fewer comparisons for insert and extract than the "standard" heap methods.

Comment: thanks so much, @JS1. But as far as this goes, is it just an often overlooked fact that a standard merge sort is, then, likely much faster than a standard heap sort because of the number of comparisons?

Comment: As far as I know, merge sort has always been known to be faster in general than heapsort.  Heapsort is one of the slowest O(N log N) sorts.  I wrote a sorting comparison once and found that quicksort and mergesort were much faster than heapsort (although I did the "standard" heapsort).  You can [take a look at this paper as well, which compares various sorts including an improved heapsort](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.385.5412&rep=rep1&type=pdf).